# Sublime Text 2 - Encoding UTF-8 não funciona

Tags: sublime-text-2, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou com problemas na edição do código, não consigo modificar o Encoding para UTF-8 de acordo como está em meu código logo abaixo. Seleciono a opção no Sublime "File> Reopen with Encoding> UTF-8" mas não funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Estou usando](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6P1l.jpg):

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Obs.: Utilizo o Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 5):

Tente salvar com a codificação UTF-8 sem BOM, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Gabriel, funcionou! Abs