# Decodificação Mysql - Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

Boa tarde,
tenho uma procedure no MYSQL que retorna informações do processamento.

```
 ELSE
    IF(linhas_banco_in_p <> 0) THEN
        SET msg = 'ESSA CONTA E AGÊNCIA JÁ EXISTE NESSE BANCO, VERIFIQUE AS INFORMAÇÕES E TENTE NOVAMENTE';
        SELECT msg;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE

        INSERT INTO banco (
                nome_banco,
```

Essa mensagem retorna e é exibida via Javascript na tela de cadastro, dentro de um modal.
O problema é que os caracteres estão vindo dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Tentei usando a função charset='utf-8' dentro da tag JavaScript, sem sucesso.
Como faço para corrigir?

Obrigado

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação server side você está usando em sua aplicação?

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente é questão de salvar sua procedure no encoding certo, veja nas opções do seu editor de código (ou utilitário de DB) como salvar como UTF-8 (ou o encoding que for usar na sua página e principalmente compatível com a tabela do DB).

Uma alternativa (menos nobre nesse caso, não é solução global) é usar *entities* (mas verifique a compatibilidade com o padrão de HTML usado):

```
SET msg = 'ESSA CONTA E AG&Ecirc;NCIA J&Aacute; EXISTEM NESSE BANCO,
           VERIFIQUE AS INFORMA&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES E TENTE NOVAMENTE'
```

Se tiver mais algum problema do lado do PHP e MySQL, provavelmente a solução está aqui:

> [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/70)

E, se estiver usando algum editor de código específico...

como Sublime Text, por exemplo, a solução está aqui:

> [Sublime Text 2 - Encoding UTF-8 não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6051/70)

Para NetBeans:

> [Netbeans bagunçando acentuação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33712/70)

Para outros editores é sempre a mesma lógica. Ao salvar, escolher a codificação correta.